# HTML Javascript - URL animation

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen one web site which demonstrates url animation. I think they are just updating url infinitly using javascript. is there any other solution to achieve it?

[Example](http://glench.com/hash)

Comment: What do you mean, so do you want a solution that does not use JavaScript? If so you can't, unless you count the user clicking a bunch of links to make an "animation" in the URL.

Comment: You could redirect the client, but that propably would be a huge mess. +1 for the table-flip though ;)

Comment: I... have no idea why anyone would *want* to do this.